# Passing Int variable to re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying pass year variable to re.findall, but it doesn't work(no errors).
Can anyone specify where I'm going wrong?

`year=2013`
`links = re.findall(r"('+year+'-.*\/t.*.html)", line)`

Comment: What is `r` here?

Comment: r ---> Raw string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year` should be out of the quotes, since it is a variable:

```
year = 2013
links = re.findall(r + '(' + str(year) + '-.*\/t.*.html)', line)
```

Comment: r is not a variable but denotes raw string. This should probably be: r'(' + str(year) + r'-.*...